# Setting text color of a TD in xsl

Tags: css

I need to display some columns in different color, i have a .xsl file that contains definition of my table. In the below code i am setting the color of the columns to red, the 'Name' column displays in red, but the 'Date' column does not display in red. If I remove the `dataType="date"` from the Date td, the Date column also starts displaying in red, i am using the `dataType="date"` only for formatting the date value from my java-script code.  Is there anything extra i have to add to change the color in this place.

```
 <td style="color=red;width=80px;" dataType="date">
    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
 </td>
 <td style="color=red;width=120px;">
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
 </td>
```

The java-script code is as below, this will just format the date to dd/mm/yyyy format.

```
function formatTable(table)
```

{
  var formatedDate;
  var colTDs = table.all.tags("TD");
  for (var i = 0; i < colTDs.length; i++)
  {
      var td = colTDs[i];

```
var sDataType = td.getAttribute("dataType");
if (sDataType == null)
  continue;
td.dataType = sDataType;
formatedDate = applyFormatDate(td.innerText); //This will just format the date to dd/mm/yyyy
td.innerText = formatedDate;
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<td style="color:red;width:80px;" data-Type="date">
    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
 </td>
```

Your CSS properties should be assigned like this:

```
Properties:value;
```

not like this:

```
Properties=value;
```

EDIT :

```
dataType=""
```

is not a valide HTML5 attribute and should be :

```
data-Type=""
```

Comment: I have tried that, it still does not work. With both the ways the second column works fine.

Comment: you said in your question that you use `dataType` only to format via javascript you date?Am I right? could you edit your question and post some of your javascript? I am thinking you might overwrite your css styling in there.

Comment: I also notice that if you are using HTML 5 your `dataType` should be spelled `data-type` thus making a valide HTML5 attribute. If you are not using HTML5 I dont think the `datatype` attribute is a valide attribute for HTML4.

Comment: The javascript will just change the format the css styling is not modified there. I am using the xsl in a .asp page to transform with a xml, the datatype is my attribute.